# How to filter on most recent value for specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running a query that has multiple rows showing db table statistics, in both a before and after status after a scheduled job that runs on either Sat/Sun.

```
Select [batchNum] ,[RunDate] ,[tableName] ,[numberofRows] ,[dataSize]
FROM TableNames
ORDER BY RunDate ASC
```

The before/after is differentiated by the batch number. So for example, this table has batch numbers 2-159. Where '158' is the 'before' job/batch from the scheduled job that ran this past weekend, and batch 159 would be the 'after.

```
    batchNum    RunDate             tableName   numberofRows    dataSize 
    158         06/04/2017 04:30:51 TableData1  1700            104        
    158         06/04/2017 04:30:51 TableData2  1276             99
    158         06/04/2017 04:30:51 TableData3  1700            157        
    158         06/04/2017 04:30:51 TableData4   200             47        

    159         06/04/2017 05:30:51 TableData1  1500             85        
    159         06/04/2017 05:30:55 TableData2  1134             94        
    159         06/04/2017 05:30:57 TableData3  1500            101        
    159         06/04/2017 05:30:59 TableData4   167             40
```

Since the batch will always be revolving, I'd like to filter this query to only return rows of most recent batchNum for the most recent weekend, any time i run it through out the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select [batchNum], [RunDate], [tableName], [numberofRows], [dataSize]
  FROM TableNames t1
 where not exists(select *
                    from TableNames t2
                   where t2.batchNum > t1.batchNum)
 ORDER BY RunDate ASC;
```

Comment: That did it. I wasn't sure if I was describing the need accurately, but this produced exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Doctorj77 Make sure to try the other methods and compare the query plan. One may be more efficient than another. Plus you will learn something, hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Make a subquery with this in the select and all the other data you need:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableName ORDER BY batchNum DESC) [rownum]
```

Then take `WHERE rownum = 1` in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for most recent batch and rundate record then you can query as below:

```
Select top 1 [batchNum], [RunDate], [tableName], [numberofRows], [dataSize]
   From yourtable
   Order by BatchNum desc, RunDate desc
```

If you are looking for recent RunDate record for every batch then you can query as below:

```
Select top(1) with ties [batchNum], [RunDate], [tableName], [numberofRows], [dataSize] From yourtable
   Order by row_number() over(partition by BatchNum order by RunDate desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from (
Select [batchNum] ,[RunDate] ,[tableName] ,[numberofRows] ,[dataSize],
row_number() over(partition by tableName  order by batchNum desc) rang
FROM TableNames
) tmp where rang=1
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution :

```
with maxi as
(
 select [tableName], max([batchNum]) MaxNum TableNames
 group by [tableName]
)
Select f1.*
FROM TableNames f1 
inner join maxi f2 on f1.tableName=f2.tableName and f1.batchNum=f2.MaxNum
```